# Remover tags HTML de um Input com PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma que verifique se, dentro de um determinado texto, existe a presença de `html`, `css` ou `script` e, se houver, remova-os.

Tenho no meu site um `input` onde os usuário colocam um texto para ser publicado. Mesmo com um "*obs.somente texto*", alguns usuários inserem *tags* indesejadas.

De que forma posso contornar isso?

Comment: Aproveitando o momento, leia o [guia de como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking), principalmente a parte de como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável. Seguir os guias com certeza farão aumentar a qualidade do conteúdo na comunidade.

Answer (score 5):

## [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php)

<sub>(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)</sub>

Retira as tags HTML e PHP de uma string.

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

Esta função tenta retornar uma string retirando todas as tags HTML e PHP de str. Usa o mesmo sistema para retirar as tags do que [fgetss()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetss.php).

#### Parâmetros

- **str**: A string de entrada.
- **allowable_tags**: Você pode utilizar o segundo parâmetro, que é opcional, para indicar *tags* que não devam ser retiradas.

> **Nota**: Comentários HTML e tags PHP também são retirados. E isto não pode ser modificado com `allowable_tags`.

#### Retorno

Retorna a string modificada.

---

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text); // Test paragraph. Other text
```

Veja o exemplo rodando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/YRsJx8).